# Showing all solutions of an ODE exist and remain bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the system
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &=-x+y \\
\dot{y} &= kx-y-xz\\
\dot{z} &= -z+xy
\end{align}
$$
where $k>0$. We want to show all solutions exist and remain bounded for $t\ge 0$. The right hand side of the system, when viewed as a vector field, is of course continuous, so we can apply Peano's existence theorem to see that all solutions exist. I'm not so sure on how to show the boundedness though (I feel like most of these types of problems follow a pattern).

What I was thinking was writing the system as so:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\z\end{pmatrix}' = \begin{pmatrix} -1 && 1 && 0 \\k && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && -1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\z\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ -xz \\xy\end{pmatrix}
$$
There's a nice theorem that says if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix having only eigenvalues with negative real part and $g:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and locally Lipschitz in $x$ such that $g(t,0)=0$ for all $t$, and
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \frac{||g(t,x)||}{||x||} = 0,
$$
then the $0$ solution of $x' = Ax+g(t,x)$ is asymptotically stable. I was hopeful, since indeed $F(x,y,z) = (0,-xz,xy)$ satisfies the assumptions of $g$ in the above theorem, but the problem is the eigenvalues of our $A$ are $-1, -1-k,$ and $-1+k$. The first two are always negative, and the last is negative only if, in addition, $k<1$, so I can't apply this theorem (though, I suppose even if all solutions converged to $0$, it might not guarantee boundedness).

On the other hand, by Liouville's formula, if $X(t)$ is a fundamental matrix, then $\det X(t) = \det X(0) e^{-3t}$, which goes to $0$, but I'm not sure how helpful that is.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the second equation is $\dot{y} = -kx-y-xz$?

In that case, multiply the first equation by $kx$, the second by $y$ and the third by $z$ and add all together. Then
$$\frac{1}{2} f'(t)=-f(t)$$
where $f(t)=y^2(t)+z^2(t)+kx^2(t)$ which implies that, for $k>0$, $x$, $y$, $z$ are bounded. In fact by integrating the ODE above we get, for $t\geq 0$,
$$\ln(f(t))=-2t+C\implies f(t)=\exp(-2t+C)\leq e^C.$$

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not $-kx-y-xz$, but the professor who writes these quals as definitely made some mistakes on other problem statements, so it could be.